# Validar un arreglo en PHP para encontrar duplicados segun condicion

Tags: postgresql, php7, php8

Arreglo en PHP encontrar una fila o llave duplicada y en caso de encontrar, sumar una columna de montos para luego crear un arreglo nuevo sin el duplicado pero con la suma de los montos.

ejemplo del arreglo:
`(id, codigo,   orden,   lote, monto, tipo)`
`[0] (1, 'SSS001', '000001', '---', 400,  'A')`
`[1] (1, 'SSS001', '000001', '---', 500,  'A')`
`[2] (1, 'SSS003', '000002', '---', 100,  'B')`
`[3] (1, 'SSS003', '000002', '---', 100,  'B')`

para este caso el arreglo final deberia quedar asi;

`[0] (1, 'SSS001', '000001', '---', 900, 'A')`
`[1] (1, 'SSS003', '000002', '---', 200, 'B')`

condicion: encontrar repetidos para los tipos; A y B... retornar un arreglo final como el indicado. y de encontrar un solo duplicado para un tipo (A o B) retornar el arreglo actualizado;

`[0] (1, 'SSS001', '000001', '---', 900,  'A')`
`[1] (1, 'SSS003', '000002', '---', 100,  'B')`
`[2] (1, 'SSS003', '000002', '001', 100,  'B')`

de lo contrario si no encuentra duplicados se retorna el arreglo original. y donde pueden ver que mi llave es: "id, codigo,   orden,   lote"

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: En tu ejemplo de arreglo no hay ningún lote 001, ¿cómo puede haber en tu arreglo resultado un lote 001?